# Target specific ul inside of div to assign list-style:none to

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a div that has two UL's inside of it. I want to apply list-style:none to the first UL's LI element (it only has one).

However, when I try to do this, it applies to the 2nd UL as well. Please help!

```css
div.com-amazon-webstore-LeftNavBrowse-2 ul:nth-child(1) li {
  list-style: none!important;
}
div.com-amazon-webstore-LeftNavBrowse-2 ul.linkList.browseLadder li {
  list-style: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="com-amazon-webstore-LeftNavBrowse-2">
  <ul class="linkList browseLadder">
    <li> <a href="http://www.test.com/b/class=tier1&amp;ie=UTF8">
                  Products
                </a> 
    </li>
    <ul class="linkList browseLadder">
      <li> <span class="current"> Hot &amp; Cold Therapy</span> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="http://www.test.com/b/6831886011">
                      PT &amp; Chiro Supplies
                    </a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="http://www.test.com/b/6831888011">
                      Massage Products
                    </a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="http://www.test.com/b/6831889011">
                      Exercise &amp; Fitness
                    </a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="http://www.test.com/b/6831890011">
                      Pain Relief Gels
                    </a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="http://www.test.comb/6831891011">
                      Rehabilitative Care
                    </a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="http://www.test.com/b/6831893011">
                      Footcare
                    </a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="http://www.test.com/b/6831894011">
                      Hand Therapy
                    </a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your second list is inside first one that does not make it a direct child of div. so you can select the first list directly with.

`.com-amazon-webstore-LeftNavBrowse-2 > ul > li`

for the second list you can use selector

`.com-amazon-webstore-LeftNavBrowse-2 > ul > li`

```css
.com-amazon-webstore-LeftNavBrowse-2 > ul > li {
                   background-color:gray;
                 }

                 .com-amazon-webstore-LeftNavBrowse-2 > ul > ul > li {
                   background-color:green;
                 }
```

```html
<div class="com-amazon-webstore-LeftNavBrowse-2">
                  <ul class="linkList browseLadder">
                      <li> <a href="http://www.test.com/b/class=tier1&amp;ie=UTF8">
                          Products
                        </a> </li>
                      <ul class="linkList browseLadder">
                          <li> <span class="current"> Hot &amp; Cold Therapy</span> </li>
                          <li> <a href="http://www.test.com/b/6831886011">
                              PT &amp; Chiro Supplies
                            </a> </li>
                          <li> <a href="http://www.test.com/b/6831888011">
                              Massage Products
                            </a> </li>
                          <li> <a href="http://www.test.com/b/6831889011">
                              Exercise &amp; Fitness
                            </a> </li>
                          <li> <a href="http://www.test.com/b/6831890011">
                              Pain Relief Gels
                            </a> </li>
                          <li> <a href="http://www.test.comb/6831891011">
                              Rehabilitative Care
                            </a> </li>
                          <li> <a href="http://www.test.com/b/6831893011">
                              Footcare
                            </a> </li>
                          <li> <a href="http://www.test.com/b/6831894011">
                              Hand Therapy
                            </a> </li>
                      </ul>
                  </ul>
              </div>
```

You can cjange background color to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
div ul:first-child li {
    list-style: none;}
```